# Pyspark Table Name with Timestamp

Tags: pyspark, timestamp, concatenation, save, databricks

I'm working in databricks coding in Pyspark. I'm encountering issues with renaming an existing table and adding a time stamp. The table is located mydatabase.tableOne, and I want to save it as another table called mydatabase.tableOne_20230625. This will allow the new process to run, creating a new version of mydatabase.tableOne

```
df_my_loc = 'mydatabase.tableOne'
timestamp_suffix = date_format(current_timestamp(), 'yyyyMMdd')
df_my_loc_new = df_my_loc + '_' + timestamp_suffix
df_arch = spark.table(df_my_loc)
df_arch.write.format("delta").mode("ignore").saveAsTable(df_my_loc_new)
```

I get an error that says the column is not iterable. It seems like adding the timestamp as a suffix is giving me the error. Before running a new process, the goal is to archive the previous table with a timestamp and run a notebook for the new output where the table names do not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date_format` and `current_timestamp` are [Spark SQL functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#current_timestamp). If used in Python, like in your example, their return type is [`Column`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html). This:

This:

```
df_my_loc_new = df_my_loc + '_' + timestamp_suffix
```

is a Python expression - concatenation of simple strings. You cannot concatenate `String` and `Column` of type String. You can either:

- concatenate Python string using `+` operator
- or concatenate SQL strings using `concat` function

Since building a table name is pure Python you just need to do:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp_suffix = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m')
```

This will yield `timestamp_suffix` as a simple string in YYYYMM format and your code will work.